# Create multiple DataFrames from a single DataFrame based on conditions by columns

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

New to pandas and python so thank you in advance.
I have a table

[image: LAB DATA]

```
# Create DataFrame
data = [{'analyte': 'sample1'},
        {'analyte': 'bacon', 'CAS1': 1},
        {'analyte': 'eggs', 'CAS1': 2},
        {'analyte': 'money', 'CAS1': 3, 'CAS2': 1, 'Value2': 1.11},
        {'analyte': 'shoe', 'CAS1': 4},
        {'analyte': 'boy', 'CAS1': 5},
        {'analyte': 'girl', 'CAS1': 6},
        {'analyte': 'onion', 'CAS1': 7, 'CAS2': 4, 'Value2': 6.53},
        {'analyte': 'sample2'},
        {'analyte': 'bacon', 'CAS1': 1},
        {'analyte': 'eggs', 'CAS1': 2, 'CAS2': 1, 'Value2': 7.88},
        {'analyte': 'money', 'CAS1': 3},
        {'analyte': 'shoe', 'CAS1': 4, 'CAS2': 3, 'Value2': 15.5},
        {'analyte': 'boy', 'CAS1': 5},
        {'analyte': 'girl', 'CAS1': 6},
        {'analyte': 'onion', 'CAS1': 7}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Before Write Pandas DataFrame into a MySQL Database Table, i need to split df to separate tables, and then write each table to Mysql

How to split df by columns, somethink like, if column name contains string "cas1" then split df

```
for col in df.columns:
    if "cas1" in col:
       dfCas1 = df.split
       #add uniq index to indetify to which row belongs to
    if "cas2" in col:
       dfCas2 = df.split
       #add uniq index to indetify to which row belongs to
    if {"analyte","id" .etc } in col: # main table
       dfMain = df.split

dfMain.to_sql("Main", dbConnection, if_exists='fail')
dfCas1.to_sql("cas1", dbConnection, if_exists='fail')
dfCas2.to_sql("cas2", dbConnection, if_exists='fail')
```

expected
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve, but I feel like you want to do something like splitting this:

```
+---------+----+------+--------+------+--------+
| Analyte | id | CAS1 | value1 | Cas2 | Value2 |
+---------+----+------+--------+------+--------+
|         |    |      |        |      |        |
+---------+----+------+--------+------+--------+
```

to this:

```
+---------+----+  +------+--------+  +------+--------+
| Analyte | id |  | CAS1 | value1 |  | Cas2 | Value2 |
+---------+----+  +------+--------+  +------+--------+
|         |    |  |      |        |  |      |        |
+---------+----+  +------+--------+  +------+--------+
```

The first one is obtained by calling e.g. `df.loc[:, ['Analyte', 'id']]`. For the other ones, adjust the column names.

Now for the *uniq index* that is within your code comments, `df.loc[:]` keeps the index of the original table. You can use [df.reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to reset it to a unique integer index. If you also want to drop empty rows in one of your subtables before parsing, have a look at [df.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Comment: yes, but each table must contains one more columns "UniqIndex"

Comment: Is this UniqIndex currently the index of your dataframe? If so, just call [df.reset_index(drop=False)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). If not, call it twice! Depending on how the new column is named, you could subsequently call `df.rename(index={'oldname':'UniqIndex'})`

Comment: yes and no, it must be best, hash of each md5(Analyte), i update question

Comment: I guess this would work:

`import hashlib`

`df.loc[:, 'Uniq'] = df.loc[:, 'Analyte'].str.encode('utf8').apply(lambda x: (hashlib.md5(x).hexdigest()))`

Comment: which one? and i need Contain string in column names first, so `df.loc[:, ['Analyte', 'id']]` will not work, also Uniq column not exists at all, so it must be generated

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean? By hashing as described above, you will append a column to the frame. Now in the selection, just make sure you order the columns accordingly in .loc. So when the order of the columns is `['Analyte', 'Something', 'Uniq']` after hashing, calling `df.loc[:, 'Uniq', 'Analyte', ' Something']` will give you the first table.

Comment: with hashing is ok, i need found columns i dont know their names only prefix

Comment: You can pass a list to .loc. If you generate this by `selection = ['Uniq'] + [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('yourPrefix')]`, then just do `df.loc[:, selection]`

Comment: TY, that work, last question, how to say what take all others left columns and put to Main df? df.loc[:, ~selection] ?

Comment: I would just add an inverse selection: `inv_selection = [col for col in df.columns if col not in selection]` and then use inv_selection in .loc

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you mean, but:

```
dfCas1 = df[df.col.str.contains('cas1')]
dfCas2 = df[df.col.str.contains('cas2')]
dfMain = df[~((df.col.str.contains('cas2')) & df.col.str.contains('cas1'))]
```

The ~ sign negates the selection and means all rows where the columns do not contain cas1 and cas2. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: But if i need multiple contains value for dfCas1? and how to add uniq index to each df so then i can verify vrom which rows come field in other df, say analyte is Product, and others columns this product attributes, so i must know where to find each products it attribute

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'

Comment: col here should be replaced by your column name. But I see you have found your answer.